# it is possible to validate json schema on mule 4 munit assert?

Tags: mule, schema, munit

In Postman tests I can validate if response has a given schema:

```
var jsonObject = pm.response.json();

var schemaResponse = {
   "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ok": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "operation_id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "push_ids": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "message_ids": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "content_urls": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "localized_ids": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


pm.test("Response Schema Validation", function() {
    var result = tv4.validateResult(jsonObject, schemaResponse);
    pm.expect(result.valid).to.be.true;
});
```

Can I do the same in Mule 4 Munit tests?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box option to do it. If you need a simple workaround you can use [json-schema-validator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/json-module/2.1/json-schema-validation) as one of your validation steps. The problem with this is it will not throw an `AssertionException`, but a `JSON:SCHEMA_NOT_HONOURED` error, due to which your test will be treated as **Errored out** instead of the expected **Failed**. Therefore I will not recommend this approach.

The correct way to do this is to create your own custom assertion and use [`Run Custom Event Processor`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.3/run-custom-event-processor). The official MuleSoft document ([link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.3/run-custom-event-processor)) describes the process with a simple and good explanation on how to implement a custom assertion class.

Basically, you will need to create a Java class that will implement `MunitAssertion` interface and use a Java Library to do the schema validation. You can pick from a variety of Java library available like [everit-org/json-schema](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema)